# How do you learn and remember 左 and 右?

Tags: word, writing

Because 左 and 右 are so similar in the shape, I am wondering how do you learn and remember them? I need a good method to teach.

Comment: You could remember that "right" (右) has a "box" in it. Boxes have with *right* angles, you see.

Comment: Plus 1. Good. We are so lucky that right angle is the same right.

Comment: 右有口 could be used to remember one, and consequently both.

Comment: What about pinyin, You4 and Kou3.

Comment: It's not that hard to remember 2 things. I wouldn't bother spending time to find a mnemonic.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster What I see is that those are harder than, say, 前 and 后.

Comment: @PdotWang Take a pencil, write them down a few times over a few days and you are done. This has the added benefit that you train your writing skills/calligraphy. Making up and learning unobvious mnemonics is an added effort.

Comment: Remembering the characters isn't difficult: 左 (zuǒ) has a similar sound with 工作 (gōngzuò) and you write it with the 工, and 右 (yòu) has a 口 (kǒu.) If you have trouble remembering left from right, you still will have trouble in another language. Perhaps it's tattoo-back-of-the-hand time :P

Comment: L E F T ~~ 工， R G ~~ 口, try to imagine the shape.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did some research, but all I can find is that both 左 and 右 are actually the same symbol that denotes hand but reversed horizontally in ancient times. This symbol basically formed the top part of the character, which now pointed at same direction.

When I was in kindergarten, my teach used to help us to remember them by telling us 右 has a 口 in it, so it's the hand you use to hold chopsticks and eat since at the time left-hand dominance was considered to be corrected. That's why in China, you almost would not see people write or hold chopsticks with their left hand even it's their dominate hand.

Answer (score 3):

左 looks like it has an "I" in it.  I in the alphabet is closer to L (left obviously)

右 looks like it has an "O" in it.  O in the alphabet is closer to R (right obviously)

Comment: I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R

Comment: I, ... , O Maybe better

Answer (score 2):

I learned it had something to do with what you do with your hands, the only one I can recall right now is how I differentiate:

When you are working (工) you hold a ruler in left hand and draw with your right.

Comment: the (right) hand brings food to the mouth (口).

Comment: Better than the way I did it.  As a follow up the student can read the Chinesebreeze book *Left and Right: The Conjoined Brothers* and never forget it after that.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty   Hi, we have a logic loop problem. If I do not remember 左 and 右, how could I read the book? But if I do not read the book, how do I remember 左 and 右?

Comment: Doesn't work for lefties :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're a bricklayer you hold your square bricks in your right hand, you hold a level or ruler in your left.  The 口 is your brick, the 工 is your level.

Cheers,

-dlj.

Answer (score 2):

In my brain association with politics works well.
The LEFT usually support workers (左 has 工 in it)
The RIGHT supports the rich and the rich always has food to eat (右 has 口 in it)

Answer (score 1):

That's how I remember it, there is one char call 有(you 3) which is similar to 右(you 4) which could help you remember the sound; but for connecting with English world, I think @Alex Quan's memory hint is great :)

Answer (score 1):

"You are right" is a mnemonic for

右 (yòu) being right (right-hand-side)

This is what someone taught me.

Answer (score 1):

工口 look like the number 10. 1 is on the left, and 0 is on the right.

Answer (score 0):

The word work has an anvil and this is in ancient times associated with work.
The word right has a mouth, you bring food to your mouth with your right hand.

Answer (score 0):

I like the right-angle one, as written above.
One that worked for me, being a lefty, is that 左 looks like it has the English character/word "I" in it. And "I" am a "left"y.

Answer (score 0):

The one that i used is that i like z more than y, and right more that left, so opposite and so z is for left and y is for left.
If u don't understand its ok, cos i know its not really a good method

Also i liked the one about right angles